# How can I remove merged-xyz.js from Typo3 8.7 Backend?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I have a problem with the extension `alm_iconpicker`. This creates a new content element with a popup window and some Javascript. I deleted the `typo3temp` folder, and now I get a 404 of a merged js-file:

> /typo3/typo3temp/assets/compressed/merged-adc822bc42f4d0d49c1bddf919a03b2a.js

I uninstall the extension and install it again, I clear all caches from `TYPO3` but this file doesn't be created new. In earlier versions of `TYPO3` I could say, no concatenates in the backend. But in `8.7` I don't find this option. Also I change the Mode to develope but still the same error. I search in the Database for the file, but I don't find it.

What can I do?

Comment: Aside from the files there are DB entries. You can try to delete all temporary files (of category concatenated) in the install-tool. or rebuild the index of your files (scheduler job)

Comment: I have no category concatenated in install tool under clean up. How can I rebuild the index

Comment: there was a subfolder compressor/ in the typo3temp/ folder. in the scheduler there is a jobs called `File Abstraction Layer: Update storage index`. if the scheduler is not called by a cron job, you need to call the task by hand (multiple times).